# Flutter Add custom auth headers to StreamChat

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

I am having issues when using Custom CDN configurations (my own server) to store Image attachments on my Stream Chat Flutter project because I cannot set the headers when the images are downloaded.

I followed the tutorial to [have my custom CDN set up](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/file_uploads/?language=dart&q=custom%20event#using-your-own-cdn).

I am using a custom SpringBoot application that authorizes using Oauth, everything is working but the HTTP requests need an [Authorization header in order to work](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/) (Bearer ).

Files get uploaded as expected, but when the images are displayed in the chat thread, they fail. The failure is because the HTTP Get request is not authenticated.

When StreamChat is using the CachedNetworkImage to download the image from my own server, it is not setting the headers for it to work and my server is returning a 401. I have the necessary headers available in my Flutter application and I am using them to upload the files successfully.

My question is, how can I set the headers correctly when these images are being requested on the Flutter side?

Do I need to override the image messageBuilder to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to override the `image` `attachmentBuilder` and pass your customised builder. You can do it using the `messageBuilder` property of the `StreamMessageListView`.

You can read more here:
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/stream_chat_flutter/stream_message_list_view/#building-custom-messages

Also, feel free to create an issue on the repo if something needs to be clarified.
https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-flutter/issues/new/choose